# HIVE - Get All matched text from string column

Tags: regex, hive

I am trying to extract all the urls from string field (metainfo.body) using query:

```sql
select split(regexp_replace(metainfo.body,'.*?((http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-]))\\n','$1#'),'#')**
```

Its not returning the URLs only but the complete field only. What should I change in this hive query to get the list of URLs?

eg:

```
select regexp_replace('hello hi i am arun http://a.com https://b.com','.*?((http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-]))','$1,') as output
```

output:

```
hello hi i am arun http://a.com https://b.com
```

Expected:

```
   http://a.com,https://b.com,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using case insensitive.
Then add a optional white space `\s*` or `[ \t\r\n]*` at the end.

Your regex turned into all ascii without the word class `\w` :

```
.*?((?:https?|ftp)://[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+[#%&+-:=?-Z\^_a-z~]*[#%&+\-/-9=?-Z\^_a-z~])\s*
```

---

The REGEXP_REPLACE should globally replace all found pattern in the string.
I can't test it, but from some online examples that use split like you're doing
should work.

```
select split(regexp_replace('hello hi i am arun http://a.com https://b.com',
'.*?((?:https?|ftp)://[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+[#%&+-:=?-Z\^_a-z~]*[#%&+\-/-9=?-Z\^_a-z~])\s*',
'$1,'), ',');
```

Here is a test of the regex using PCRE and its replacement
https://regex101.com/r/lIEvCk/1

Other references:
[here 1](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-to-use-regexp-replace-in-hive-to-remove-special/td-p/233568)
[here 2](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-user/201406.mbox/%3CCAO78En+Ptz8a=d3+dDRgMfuxhqOosXWE5y2OMtocjrCMaBPvww@mail.gmail.com%3E)

Comment: updated the question

Comment: @ArunSinghal - I updated with sample using the `REGEX_REPLACE`. Yours should have worked. My suggestion is to try your regex and replacement at an online regex testing site. If ok, then look into the escaping of your sample string / regex / replacement strings.